# LESS CSS nested loops for header elements

Tags: css, less, nested-loops

first post,

My question is this,

Is it **possible** to do a less loop for iterated elements (*rather than iterated classes/ids*) and if so **what** am I doing wrong and **how** would I do it otherwise?

```
.generate-columns(4);

.generate-columns(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
    .column-@{i} {
        width: (@i * 100% / @n);
    }
    .generate-columns(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

Above is the example generic loop show on the [less features page](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature),
It's really interesting I feel so I wondered what circumstance I could use it for.
I thought that autogenerating header element fontsizes for different header sizes would be perfect; below is my attempt

```
.headers-generator(6);

.headers-generator(@n, @i : 1) when (@i =< @n)
{
    h@{i}{
        font-size: (2em - ((@i - 1) * 0.2)em);
    }
        .headers-generator(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

Below is the expected output

```
h1
{
    font-size: 2em;
}
h2
{
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
h3
{
    font-size: 1.6em;
}
h4
{
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
h5
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
h6
{
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

I am using **Visual Studio 2012** and **Web Essentials**,
Web Essentials' error for this LESS is "missing a colon between property and value" and it also tells me that the `@i` and `@n` inside the curly brackets are "undeclared".

Input much appreciated.

Comment: Have you got the latest version of Web Essentials 2012?  Sounds to me like you are using an older version of LESS that does not support property interpolation (needs to be less 1.6 and above)

Comment: I am worried it is a Web Essentials issue, I have updated Web Essentials as far as visual studio deems is up to date.

Is it likely that web essentials would update without informing VS?
I have on previous occasions been prompted by visual studio to update.

I have just checked **Tools/Extensions and Updates/** in the "installed" and "Updates" sections but there appears to be no newer version, nor does W.E.s web site say the version of LESS.

Comment: The changelog states that LESS 1.6.3 is used in the latest version (3.7) http://vswebessentials.com/changelog

Comment: Well colour me impressed, I should have seen the change log.
I'll uninstall and reinstall Web Essentials and get back to you.

Comment: reinstalled via VS and reinstalled by downloading it from the website just encase they're different release versions, errors remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mixin will work in LESS 1.6+.  The `em` at the end of the font-size calculation was kicking up an error and is not necessary as `em`  units are already being used in the calculation.

```
.headers-generator(@n; @i : 1) when (@i =< @n)
{
  h@{i} {
    font-size: (2em - (@i - 1) * 0.2);    
  }

  .headers-generator(@n; (@i + 1));
}

.headers-generator(6);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you, annoying/reassuring to know it was only "em" wrong.

Comment: Just in case there's no "property interpolation" in this code. Selector interpolation (with given syntax) is supported since v1.4.x.